# Limit the number of objects in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a poll application. And this is the only one poll on my site. I need to have only one poll and admin should not be able to create more than one.
if a poll exists, there must be no "Add poll" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this method to `PollAdmin`:

```
def has_add_permission(self, request):
    return Poll.objects.all().count() == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using django > 1.2.

```
class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

   def has_add_permission(self, request):
       return not Poll.objects.exists()   # cheaper than Poll.objects.count() on most of the db
```

Comment: It works correctly for me, if it has already a poll. But if I delete the only poll, I can't add new one.